# Original idea for the MVC pattern

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, model-view-controller

What is the original idea for the MVC pattern? I'm trying to understand the pattern better, but with all the little variations you come across it makes it difficult to understand what the original was, so I can actually know which parts are changeable and which aren't. I get the way the Ruby on Rails does it,  so that controller is effectively the main entry point. However, some of the examples in Java I've seen use the controller as something to instantiate and call methods upon so that the main entry point completely avoids having to deal with implicit knowledge of the view and model. I guess what I'm trying to ask is what is the language agnostic MVC pattern?

Comment: I guess the original idea was to separate responsibility and decouple code so that it was easier to manage, update and reuse.

Comment: It makes sense to me if you consider stability of code over time, too. The elements of a models tend to stabilize in an application domain, whereas views are very ephemeral. A great example is Microsoft Word. Over the years Microsoft has modified the views of the application, but there hasn't been as much change in the model (paragraphs, sections, page layouts, styles, etc.). MVC facilitates changes to the view code without having to modify the model code, since the latter is not coupled to the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, the first academic publication was of the MVC design pattern was in 1988, describing the Smalltalk-80 version.  More history can be found in some [historical notes](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html) written by Trygve Reenskaug who is recognized as the originator of the MVC design pattern.  These date the original work as having been done 10 years earlier.  (Of course, in those days MVC was not described as a ["design pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#History).  It predates the work of Kent, Cunningham and others on applying Alexander's design patterns to software.)

An excellent and authoritative description of the MVC pattern (and what it aims to achieve) may be found on Martin Fowler's website; [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).  This article places the MVC pattern in the context of other earlier and more recent GUI design patterns, discusses the respective advantages and problems.

(Martin Fowler makes the point that a lot of GUI frameworks that other people describe as MVC are patently not MVC.  It is worth remembering this as you try to sort the concepts out in your mind.)

References:

- Krasner, Glenn E.; Pope, Stephen T. (Aug–Sep 1988). ["A cookbook for using the model–view controller user interface paradigm in Smalltalk-80"](http://www.itu.dk/courses/VOP/E2005/VOP2005E/8_mvc_krasner_and_pope.pdf). The JOT (SIGS Publications).
- Fowler, Martin. ["GUI Architectures".](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html)
- Wikipedia article on [Model View Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#History) design patterns.
- Wikipedia article on [Software Design Patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#History).

Comment: Thanks for that, was doing my head in by the sites that seem to only think in terms of their language. The historical note description of model-thing-view sounds like something I'd call a pattern :D.

Comment: Sorry, meant it in terms of naming something 'thing'.  They probably didn't because the pattern concept only came about later, I'm guessing with the Gang of Four guys.

Comment: @shred14 - Kent and Cunningham published on software design patterns in 1987, and it is an application of a concept borrowed from the Architecture (of the bricks and mortar kind) ten years earlier.  The Gang of Four book was first published in 1994.

Comment: That's cool. I guess that the 'pattern' concept had been floating around in some form or another prior to the Kent and Cunningham paper as well, the MVC paper would definitely suggest that. They simply gave it a name and formalized it, but then again I'm not familiar with this side of computer science academia. Thanks!